# How to Create Dynamic Line in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to draw a line in crystal report which can be suppress in special situations.

For example:

```
Value1|Value2|Value3
```

If Value3 is `null` then result is:

```
Value1|Value2
```

**Any suggestion?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that the best way to create dynamic line as you said ,is using borders. you can use Text objects borders to create your line and you can create a formula to change the border color to white in your special situations.this is a sample which you can use in your border color formula:

```
if {?PERCENT_RATE_IN}= -1 then
crBlack
else
crWhite ;
```